# Cannot mock response class or nullpointerException?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, java-11

I am trying to write a unit test for Response using JUnit 5 and mockito-junit-jupiter:4.8.0.
The method is simply checking the error codes :

```java
public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.error(t.getMessage(), t);
    if (t instanceof WebApplicationException) {
        return getResponse(t, ((WebApplicationException) t).getResponse().getStatus());
    }
    if (t instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
        return getResponse(t, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode());
    }
    if (t instanceof PersistenceException) {
        return getDatabaseExceptionResponse(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode());
    }
    
    return getResponse(t, Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode());
}
```

And I found pretty interesting thing.. in older project I used to mock Response class like this

```java
Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
Mockito.when(response.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);
```

which was working just fine with no issues at all. But now when I try to mock response class I either get

```
Mockito cannot mock this class: class javax.ws.rs.core.Response.
    
    Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes, but the root cause of this error might be different.
    Please check the full stacktrace to understand what the issue is.
    If you're still not sure why you're getting this error, please open an issue on GitHub.
```

Or `NullPointerException` when i try to run test without `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.

Can anyone help me with that ? thank you Peter

@edit
This is the test its parametrized junit 5 test. Please dont mind assert equals on the end I was just trying to put anything there so I can get past error

```
        @Mock
        Response mockResponse;
    
        @Mock
        Response.ResponseBuilder builder;
    
        @Mock
        Response.StatusType statusType;


    @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({
            "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,400",
            "javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException,404",
            "javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException,406",
            "javax.ws.rs.ServiceUnavailableException,503",
            "java.lang.NullPointerException,500"
        })
        void testToResponse(String className, int errorCode) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, InvocationTargetException {
    
            
     Mockito.when(Response.status(anyInt())).thenReturn(builder)
     Mockito.when(builder.entity(any())).thenReturn(builder);
     Mockito.when(builder.header(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(builder);
     Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(mockResponse);
            
    
            if (className.startsWith("javax.ws.rs.")) {
                switch (className) {
                    case "javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException":
                        when(mockResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(404);
                        break;
                    case "javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException":
                        when(mockResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(406);
                        break;
                    case "javax.ws.rs.ServiceUnavailableException":
                        when(mockResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(503);
                        break;
                }
                when(mockResponse.getStatusInfo()).thenReturn(statusType);
                when(statusType.getFamily()).thenReturn(Response.Status.Family.familyOf(errorCode));
            }
    
            Constructor<?> constructor = Class.forName(className).getConstructor(String.class);
            Object e = constructor.newInstance(MESSAGE);
    
            mapper.toResponse((Throwable) e);
            System.out.print(mockResponse.getStatus());
            assertEquals("", mockResponse.getStatus());
        }
```

Stacktrace for mockito cannot mock this class :

```
Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to invoke proxy for public abstract java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator$ForLoadedMethodReturnType$Dispatcher.getAnnotatedReturnType(java.lang.reflect.Method)
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:153)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:204)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$2(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:42)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:184)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:257)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:273)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$14(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:273)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:272)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:256)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:141)
        ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to invoke proxy for public abstract java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator$ForLoadedMethodReturnType$Dispatcher.getAnnotatedReturnType(java.lang.reflect.Method)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$ProxiedInvocationHandler.invoke(JavaDispatcher.java:1173)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.$Proxy33.getAnnotatedReturnType(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator$ForLoadedMethodReturnType.resolve(TypeDescription.java:2947)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator.asList(TypeDescription.java:2692)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfNonGenericType$ForLoadedType.getDeclaredAnnotations(TypeDescription.java:3889)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.apply(AnnotationAppender.java:743)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onNonGenericType(AnnotationAppender.java:723)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onNonGenericType(AnnotationAppender.java:425)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfNonGenericType.accept(TypeDescription.java:3670)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.MethodAttributeAppender$ForInstrumentedMethod.apply(MethodAttributeAppender.java:196)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.MethodAttributeAppender$Compound.apply(MethodAttributeAppender.java:484)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyAttributes(TypeWriter.java:712)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:702)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:611)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5959)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2213)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:232)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:204)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3668)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:288)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.lambda$mockClass$0(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:47)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:168)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:399)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:190)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:410)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:40)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:77)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:53)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:96)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1965)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:27)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:72)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:47)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:81)
    at org.mockito.internal.framework.DefaultMockitoSession.<init>(DefaultMockitoSession.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.session.DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.startMocking(DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.java:83)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1517)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.nestingForType(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:96)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedType(TypeAnnotationParser.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotatedReturnType0(Executable.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotatedReturnType(Method.java:721)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.Invoker$Dispatcher.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$Dispatcher$ForNonStaticMethod.invoke(JavaDispatcher.java:1028)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$ProxiedInvocationHandler.invoke(JavaDispatcher.java:1158)
    ... 162 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 183 more
```

I found some older articles that had this issue mockito cannot mock the class but it was from version 2.15 to 2.22. I am using 4.8.0. The issue was that when the mockito dependency was installed it downloaded unsupported version of bytebudby which was causing the issue. Bytebuddy version in my project is 1.12.9. Now there are newev version but its not the dependency I installed but dependency that mockito installed i dont have control over the version easily and I would want to avoid installing agents and stuff like that. Thanks

Comment: `jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response`? Could you please also include (i) your test class and (ii) the stack trace?

Comment: the message says to check your stacktrace - you should at least provide it in the question, even if you checked it yourself. Which Java version are you using? Which dependency does the `Response` come from?

Comment: @beatngu13 I have added test class and stack trace cyberbrain the response comes from javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

Comment: @PeterPotoma Mockito / Byte Buddy cannot find `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter` (`ClassNotFoundException`). Could you please also include your build file (e.g. `pom.xml`)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `mock` a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`- even for a test you could simply build the real thing quite easily:

```java
Response responseOk = Response.ok().build();
```

This should give you a response with an OK state. Or if you don't trust the word "ok", you could do something like

```
Response response200 = Response.status(200).build();
```

Both ways seem a lot more elegant to me, and are shorter to write and read.

To adapt your test, you could change the mocking like this:

```java
Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(Response.status(errorCode).build());
```

And then you should be able to skip your whole `if` afterwards. As it is "the real thing" it should behave correctly when it comes to the statustype, family, etc.

Comment: This is not good approach because I want to modify the value of mockResponse by mock behavior. Its parametrized test and I would need a lot of those and you cannot use this syntax in setting Mockito behavior because when I would want to use your syntax I cannot use Mockito.when(ResponseOk because when requires an argument which has to be a method call on a mock but thank you for the answer I tried it but it doesnt fix my problem.

Comment: @PeterPotoma I added an example of how you could simplify your test (didn't have the test code available when I wrote my answer), let me know if it works for you.